# Mark element if within 180 business days of one another

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have the following data.

I want to mark all entries which are within 180 business days of one another.

```
1    2009-01-16
2    2010-01-22
3    2010-02-26
4    2010-06-18
5    2013-09-11
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I've been able to do this with some `diff` shifting and boolean logic for *normal* days, but not for business ones, like below:

```
def check_dates(l):
    OVERLAP_DT = 180  # edited
    diff0 = l.diff(periods=-1).fillna(pd.Timedelta('528491 hours'))  # filler for some number greater than 180 days for NAs
    diff1 = l.diff(periods=1).fillna(pd.Timedelta('528491 hours'))
    return ((np.abs(diff0.dt.days) > OVERLAP_DT) & (np.abs(diff1.dt.days) > OVERLAP_DT)).astype(int)
```

The above outputs the following, where `1` is 'good, continue', and is correct for days. I am unsure, however, how to make this work for business days.

```
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
Name: Announcement_Date, dtype: int32
```

EDIT: Changed the index from the original copy-over to `1, 2, 3, ...` because that was confusing.

Comment: The first numbers (column) is that the index or the difference in days? So the `19, 179, 194`

Comment: Oh, whoops, it's the index

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
'1/1/2018' in pd.bdate_range(start = '1/1/2018', periods = 180)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

```
df.Date > df.Date.shift() + pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(180)
```

Output below makes more sense than your output, i.e. days at 179 and 955 are outside of 180 bday windows stating on the previous day.

```
19     False
179     True
194    False
261    False
955     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Or if you want to mark days 19 and 261 instead:

```
df.Date < df.Date.shift(-1) - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(180)
```

and output:

```
19      True
179    False
194    False
261     True
955    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: That's the index, apologies as I wasn't clear. The raw dates are, however, printed at the top.

Comment: I was referring to the index with `19`, `261` and so on. What I am trying to say is one of the `1`'s in your expected output is not correct.

Comment: They are, given that the check is on normal days. Any entry that is within 180 days of each other, where the differences are, for each element in the list: `[ -371 days, -35 days, -112 days, -1181 days, NA ]` elements `[ 2, 3, 4 ]` should be marked because each of them falls within 180 days of another element.

Comment: Oh, so you want to look compare to both day before, and day after?